# Is there a way to use wget to download a site and ALL of its requirement documents including remote ones

Tags: linux, wget

I want to do something simular to the following:

`wget -e robots=off --no-clobber --no-parent --page-requisites -r --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows  somedomain.com/s/8/7b_arbor_day_foundation_program.html`

However, the page I'm downloading has remote content from a domain other than somedomain.com. It was asked of me to download that content too. is this possible with wget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add -H or --span-hosts  (same thing)

-H,  --span-hosts                go to foreign hosts when recursive.

Comment: You are a genius! For some reason I looked right over that one when I was looking through the man file.

Comment: @General Redneck  I have a file for various commands and when I find a new switch I jot it down 'cos so much in the man pages aren't relevant to me and so man doesn't refresh my memory very well.  You can use -k(convert links) -p(images/page requisites)   e.t.c. easier to remember. there is also a wget mailing list if really stuck, questions there are really tough I can't answer those. Was a fluke that I could answer yours!   A good way to learn wget, and I haven't done this yet, is on a local web server simple pages.   I did once hear curl is better than wget.

Comment: Actually this worked perfectly and did exactly what I needed it to. I personally like verbose commands because in my mind, it's easier to remember. Thus the reason they have both styles I guess. I'll defiantly take your advice if/when I have more problems. I agree, I've heard curl was better, however, I first started the problem with wget and was apparently one option off :P, so finishing it wasn't a big deal.